# Loop a query through multiple Databases using a cursor

Tags: sql-server, cursors

I am trying to loop a query through multiple databases that I have listed in a table, I've tried to use a cursor and switch out the USE statement with the new database name but I keep getting an incorrect syntax error. Is there any way to do this? Below is my attempt.

```
Declare @storednamesDATABASE varchar(255)
Declare storednamesDBs_cursor Cursor
for
select Database_name from ##ALLTHEstorednames

Open storednamesDBs_cursor
Fetch next from storednamesDBs_cursor into @storednamesDATABASE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

Use @storednamesDATABASE
select distinct a.database_id, c.name as Database_Name, a.object_id, b.name as Table_Name,
dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),0) as Use_Date
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats a
join sys.all_objects b
on a.object_id = b.object_id
join sys.databases c
on a.database_id = c.database_id
where (a.last_user_seek between dateadd(hour, -24, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
or a.last_user_scan between dateadd(hour, -24, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
or a.last_user_lookup between dateadd(hour, -24, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
and b.type = 'u'


End
Close storednamesDBs_cursor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you're on azure you can't use "use"

Your issue is that "use" doesn't take a string (nvarchar) it takes the object name.

To achieve this you could use dynamics SQL

```
Select @Sql = 'Use ' + @storednamesDATABASE + ';  --Other SQL Here'
Exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

Though you're going to have to put the rest of your query in the Sql string because it won't change the connection you're currently in.  It effectively creates a stored procedure and runs it.

To pass parameters to your query you can use something like

```
Exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Var1 int, @Var2 nvarchar(50)', @Var1 = @SomeVar, @Var2 = 'Test'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I try that I get an empty result set. Can you help with the syntax of combining a cursor with sp_executesql?

Comment: Are you running this in code? Or an SqlServerManagementStudio?